# Excel advanced filter two values in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with multiple user ID and there answers to the question.
I would like to narrow it down to users who answer "No" to all question.

Eg

```
User ID | question ID |answer
1 | 1 | yes
1 | 2 | no
2 | 1 | no
2 | 2 | no
```

=>

```
User ID | question ID |answer
2 | 1 | no
```

When I use custom filter with answer equals "no" AND answer does not equal "yes" it still shows user 1 as he has one "no" answer.

How to proceed with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the rows for each 'User ID' and compare it with the count of rows for each 'User ID' that have "no" in 'answer'. Ctrl+T to convert your data range to a Table.

[image]

The formula:

```
=COUNTIFS([answer],"no",[[User ID ]],[@[User ID ]])=COUNTIF([[User ID ]],[@[User ID ]])
```